# RVM git has no installation candidate

Tags: ruby, git, ubuntu, rvm

I'm currently trying to install ruby via rvm on Ubuntu 10.04 with Plesk 11.
My rvm version is 1.19.3..

Unfortunately, rvm fails while installing the requirements, namely git.
The log says there is no installation candidate available.

It seems the source, rvm is receiving the .tar.bz2 file from, is outdated..
It's looking for "git-1.7.6.4.tar.bz2" on "http://kernel.org/pubs/software/scm/git/",
but there are only some files from 2005.

Therefore, the file exists of some html code stating a 404 Error only.

Has anybody an idea how to tell rvm to look for some new sources?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a bug, open a ticket for RVM here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: geez! I'm going to step down to 1.18.16 again..
I'm writing a ticket.. Thanks for the response!

Comment: 1.19.0 should be fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed with [277667e](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/277667ebe84d3446b3eb3815f39bc191e1e1cdf7).  We now allow libs to fallback to `git-core` if `git` is not available.  If you have trouble next time please be sure to file a ticket since we may not always monitor SO for RVM issues.

To test please do: `rvm get head`

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Works fine :) I did not have the time to write the ticket yesterday. Sorry for that..